# Make this-> shorter and save some time typing

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

The idea is simple use @classVar instead of this->classVar. Insipired by CoffeeScript and because explicitly accessing instance variables is a good practice.

I wanted to do this

```
#define @ this->
```

And later this

```
class MyClass{
  int foo;

  void bar(){
     @foo = 10;
  }
}
```

But GCC says @ is not an identifier and would not compile it.
As far as I am aware the @ symbol is not part of C++ standard should be freely available.

What other solutions are there to shorten **this->**?

Comment: Not an answer, but please do not do this if you want other people to be able to read your code.

Comment: In that particular case, you can shorten `this->` to nothing. `void bar(){foo=10;}` will work just fine.

Comment: `this->` is must if and only if your class variable and function parameter name are same. Ex. `void bar(int foo){ this->foo=foo;}`

Comment: Must we obscure the language's syntax further?  If you *really* insist on qualifying names where it's not needed and you're *really* worried about all that extra typing, define a template in your IDE containing `this->` and bind a keyboard shortcut to it.

Comment: Replacing `this->` with something cutesy is a bad idea unless you are intending to write obfuscated code.

Comment: This is a horrible idea. Please abandon it. If you're going to program in C++, program in C++ with C++ idioms. Don't try to make it look like some other language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Tom mentioned you do not have to use `this->` in this case. You have to use it only in the case that when your class variable and function parameter name are the same (i.e. `void bar(int foo){ this->foo=foo;}`).

If you would like to emphasize that the variable is a member variable, follow a style guide (e.g. [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html)) and name your member variables accordingly.

```
class MyClass{
  int foo_;

  void bar(){
    foo_ = 10;
  }
}
```

or

```
class MyClass{
  int mFoo;

  void bar(){
    mFoo = 10;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to check preprocessor output `cpp test.cpp > test.preprocessed` - you get an error "error: macro names must be identifiers". Macro name should start with letter

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `this` keyword with something shorter:

```
#define T this
```

and then access it like this:

```
T->foo = 10;
```

Comment: If you do that in a place with code reviews, you'll have to remove the macro and replace T with this as soon as your code gets reviewed.